# Memorymanagement in C, passing pointers in functions, segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory-management

I have three files:

#### something.h

```
typedef struct {
    int size_t;
    char *c;
} p;

p ** createMatrix(int r, int c);

void printMatrix(p **matrix, const int r, const int c);
```

#### something.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "something.h"

p **
createMatrix(int r, int c)
{
    int rowsize=r*2+1;
    int colsize=c*2+1;

    /* memory alloc of rows */
    p **matrix=malloc(rowsize*sizeof(p *));
    int k;
    for(k=0; k<rowsize; k++)
    {
        /* memory alloc of columns */
        matrix[k]=malloc(colsize*sizeof(p));
    } 
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<rowsize; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<colsize; j++)
        {
            /* columns is between letters */
            if(j%2!=0)
            {   
                matrix[i][j].size_t=7;
                matrix[i][j].c=malloc(8*sizeof(char));
                strcpy(matrix[i][j].c,"       ");
            }
            else if(i%2==0 && j%2==0)
            {
                matrix[i][j].size_t=1;
                matrix[i][j].c=malloc(sizeof(char));
                *(matrix[i][j].c)='a';
            }
            else
            {
                matrix[i][j].size_t=1;
                matrix[i][j].c=malloc(sizeof(char));
                *(matrix[i][j].c)=' ';
            }
        }
    }       
    return matrix;
}

void
printMatrix(p **matrix, const int r, const int c)
{
    int rowsize=r*2+1;
    int colsize=c*2+1;
    printf("\n");
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<rowsize; i++)
    {
        printf("\t");
        for(j=0; j<colsize; j++)
        {
            if(matrix[i][j].size_t==1)
                printf("%c", *matrix[i][j].c);
            else
                printf("%s", matrix[i][j].c);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
 }
```

#### main.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "something.h"    

void
printMenufunction(p **matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    int rowsize=rows*2+1;
    int colsize=cols*2+1;
    /* memory alloc of rows */
    matrix=malloc(rowsize*sizeof(p *));
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<rowsize; i++)
    /* memory alloc of columns */
        matrix[i]=malloc(colsize*sizeof(p));
    matrix=createMatrix(rows, cols);
}

int
main(void)
{
    int rows, cols;
    p **matrix;
    char stringtemp[3];
    printf("ask for row and col in form (5x5):\n");
    scanf("%s", stringtemp);
    sscanf(stringtemp, "%dx%d", &rows, &cols);
    printMenufunction(matrix, rows, cols);
    printMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    return 0;
}
```

This code sample that is a simplified version of my prog gives me a segmentation fault. I have debugged it with the gdb so I know its somewhere amongst these lines that the fault lies. I would be grateful for some help, thanks.

UPDATE:
I can't debug this version. My old prog with alot more code told me it was along this area, but at least I can't figure out where? So thats why I can't post what line exactly that makes the segmentation fault. If i knew I think I could have handled the problem my self. I hoped some one could see it more clearly than me..

Comment: Can you post the error messages you're getting. Do you know which line it's crashing on?

Comment: Why are you doing so many allocations.  I suggest you change the `char *c` in type `p` to a `char c[10]` and allocate the matrix as one XxY area of memory.  That will be much easier to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it would help us a *lot* for you to tell us *which* line gdb indicated was at fault instead of just saying, "it's somewhere in these lines."  gdb should be able to tell you *exactly* which line triggered the error.

Having said that, here's a candidate:

```
char *stringtemp;
printf("ask for row and col in form (5x5):\n");
scanf("%s", stringtemp);
```

`stringtemp` hasn't been assigned to point anywhere meaningful; all you have is a pointer whose initial value is *indeterminate*.  So that's one potential segfault.  Either allocate a buffer for `stringtemp` to point to, or just allocate it as an array of `char`:

```
char stringtemp[SOME_SIZE]; // where SOME_SIZE is as big as you need.
```

Why are you allocating the matrix in `printMenuFunction`?!  Why aren't you using your `createMatrix` function?!

**EDIT**

I hate getting old; I completely missed that `createMatrix` is being called from `printMenuFunction` (which means that the `malloc` calls in `printMenuFunction` are redundant and need to be eliminated).

Rewrite your `printMenuFunction` as follows:

```
void printMenuFunction(p ***matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
  *matrix = createMatrix(rows, cols);
}
```

Note that within that function, if you need to access an element of `matrix`, you will need to dereference it *before* applying a subscript, such as

```
(*matrix)[i][j].size = ...;
```

Rewrite your `main` as follows:

```
int
main(void)
{
    int rows, cols;
    p **matrix;
    char stringtemp[3]; // 3 is not big enough to hold a string like "5x5";
                        // that requires an array size of *at least* 4.  
                        // "10x10" would require 6 characters.  You need
                        // an extra character for the 0 terminator.

    printf("ask for row and col in form (5x5):\n");
    scanf("%s", stringtemp);
    sscanf(stringtemp, "%dx%d", &rows, &cols);
    printMenufunction(&matrix, rows, cols); // note the & in front of matrix
    printMatrix(matrix, rows, cols);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well the thing is that the real function printMenuFunction asks the user for more input and stuff. And I simply did not want to focus on those things to simplify. Also I want to do it this way, as I think the great thing about c is pointers, and passing not only by value as in other languages that I have come across. I have tried to debug this version too, and set the breakpoints on different places but the (gdb) says that `Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory. Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000 0x00007fff83b36bcb in __svfscanf_l ()`

Comment: And I don't know where it is occuring.

Comment: Another thing: the problem has unfortunately not to do with the stringtemp or scanf functions. I have already checked it, they work very well. Thank you anyway

Comment: @patriques: they *can't* work very well, not as written.  And given that error message, it really does feel like that is the current culprit.  Compile your code with the -g option, start it up in gdb, and then step through it line by line (set a break point at `main`, start the program, and then use `n` to step through line by line).

Comment: Ok you where right about the stringtemp variable, even though I had tested that before and it worked, but anyway, I made the changes you proposed, but it still gives me segmentation fault as before. :-(

Comment: @patriques: your `printMenuFunction` isn't allocating any memory for the `c` member of the struct to point to, so the crash is probably on the lines `printf("%c", *matrix[i][j].c);` and `printf("%s", matrix[i][j].c);`.  Same issue as the `stringtemp` problem earlier.

Comment: But I do assign memory in the createMatrix function in something.c does isn't that enough? The thing is that the size of the char * in the struct varies in size so I can only do this dynamically. How should I solve it do you propose?

Comment: @patriques: but you aren't *calling* the `createMatrix` function, at least not in the code you've supplied above, so that code is never executed.  And Binyamin Sharet is right in that you need to pass a pointer to `matrix` when you call `printMenuFunction` (you don't need it for the `printFunction`, though).

Comment: but i call it through the printMenuFunction, at least I thought I did, aren't the createMatrix call in that function returning the matrix? Im going to cry soon..

Answer (score 1):

As C is a pass-by-value language, any assignment to a function argument modifies only the local copy of the argument, so when `printMenufunction` returns, `matrix` is still not initialized.

You need to pass the pointers to matrix by reference:

```
printMenufunction(&matrix, rows, cols);
printMatrix(&matrix, rows, cols);
```

and dereference inside the functions. For example:

```
//                       v Pointer to the double-pointer
void printMenufunction(p ***matrix, int rows, int cols)
{
    int rowsize=rows*2+1;
    int colsize=cols*2+1;
    /* memory alloc of rows */
//  v Dereferencing the pointer
    *matrix=malloc(rowsize*sizeof(p *));
   // ...
}
```

Comment: You need to pass its address when you want to assign to it, not when you only want to use it.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering so quickly. A follow-up. Then I should dereference it also in the lines: `*matrix[i]=malloc(colsize*sizeof(p));
    *matrix=createMatrix(rows, cols);` Right?